# Orbeon - embed many files in form builder

Tags: orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

What is the best way to embed many files (pdf, rtf, doc) in form builder (Users can download files via form runer) paying attention to performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the performance part, but you can use the File Attachment control and set the "Read-Only" property of each control to `true()`. This way the files are attached to the form definition but the user can only download them, not change them.